# How to save the name of object in array object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array containing 7 objects named is NewClass.

[image]

When I make some changes to the objects, the object has lost its original NewClass name.

Like that:

[image]

In arrray[6] lost NewClass name.

So is there any way I can keep the NewClass name for that object?

Here is my function to handle this array:

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(layers);
if (selectedLayerIndex && layers.length > 0) {

  console.log(
    'x',
    layers.map((x) => {
      if (x.feature.properties.editLayerId === selectedLayerIndex) {
        console.log(x);

        return (x = {
          ...x,
          options: { ...x.options, color: 'cyan', fillColor: 'cyan' },
        });
      }
      return x;
    })
  );
  
}
```

}, [selectedLayerIndex]);

Thank you so much!

Comment: @brk I have updated my code above. Please help me if you can. Thank you.

Comment: share the response also

Comment: @brk About the response is an array of objects similar to that because inside each object contains a lot of properties I can't copy it all out. The important thing is that I just want to save the name of the object as NewClass even if it changes the internal properties of that class. That photo, in my opinion, is really clear.
If you can help me thank you for that otherwise I will wait for other answers or find solutions myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using the syntax `x = {...x, option: {/* some changes to the class */}` here, you change the class to a object, which cause a lost of your class name.

If you want to keep it as a class, please use instance.attribute instead, see the following example

```html
class Demo {
    constructor(color){
        this.color = color;
    }
}

var array = [new Demo('red'),new Demo('red'),new Demo('red'),new Demo('red'),new Demo('red'),new Demo('red'),new Demo('red')];

console.log('original array', array);
console.log('');

array[6] = {...array[6], color: 'blue'};
console.log(array); // array[6] have been change to a object
console.log('');

array[5].color = 'green';
console.log(array); // array[5] is still a class
console.log('');
```